# ВладимироФка

Tags: орфография, топонимика

В зоне  затопления в Приамурье оказалась деревня Владимиро**ф**ка. Указатель видно на [фото слева](http://www.echo.msk.ru/files/1014774.jpg?1376370204).

Как вообще могло появиться такое написание через "ф"?

---

**Добавление Марк Иза**
[image]

изображение [отсюда](http://www.echo.msk.ru/blog/soobshestvo/1134998-echo/)

Comment: Интересное фото, правда село Владимиро**в**ка, оказавшееся под водой, пишется без "Ф". [Фото][1]. Почему на этом указателе через "ф" не знаю.

  [1]: http://www.echo.msk.ru/files/1014632.jpg?1376364043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только опечатка или "прикол" такой. 
Есть универсальный адресный справочник, в отделе кадров или бухгалтерии спросите.

behemothus, такое название не могло сохраниться со старых времён. 
Нестандартные названия делали стандартными, когда в СССР стали выдавать паспорта колхозникам. Я столкнулась, когда в пенстрахе работала. В трудовой - одно, в паспорте - другое. Говорит, переписали в лохматом году.

Если у Вас те же проблемы, что и у меня, то картинка тут 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEXUt.png
Я правой мышкиной кнопкой беру адрес и смотрю спокойно.

Плохо, но что-то видно.

Comment: Да, пожалуй. Не подумал. Было такое. Только  не говорите про лохматый год. Кому лохматый - а кому прекрасная юность.  

Проблемы другие. Если я правильно понял, Ваши - от слабого инета или нехватки памяти на Вашем компе. Решение правильное, но в дальнейшем стоит поднять технику. И вообще, ***эта*** картинка появилась уже ***после*** моего ответа. Вопрос с картинкой ***для меня*** закрыт раз и навсегда.

Comment: @behemothus, простите за нескромный вопрос, а чем стал хуже вопрос с картинкой? Я - новичок на форуме, но вроде как от картинки вопрос стал только лучше. Спасибо @Марк Из за редактирование. Я и не знал, что тут изображения добавлять можно, ещё бы узнать как. )))

Изображение действительно странное, но похоже @irinaGLA права.

Comment: Яzz, мы закрыли тему про ***эту*** картинку.
Мы окончательно запутались в том кто, что, когда и почему говорил, не стоит поднимать. А коли уж Вы (совсем, кстати, не новичок) не против, можно ставить последнюю точку.  
Да, а по сути Ирина, конечно, права. Я это с радостью признал.

Comment: Яzz, Я не компьютерщик, но не стоит вставлять в чужие сообщения сторонние ссылки без ведома автора.  
Но проблема у меня не в этом. Если интересно, я сейчас попробую показать, что у мне с картинкой. Подождите, я плохой фотошопщик... Только вставлять никуда не буду. По тем же причинам. 

behemothus, я поняла, спасибо.

Comment: >Вот как-то так  
  
Я так и думал. Рекомендации в силе.

Answer (score 3):

Указателя, к сожалению, не вижу, но могу с определенной уверенностью сказать, что это не опечатка, во всяком случае - не современная. На Дальнем Востоке (и, возможно, Сахалине) есть несколько подобных топонимов. С одним я столкнулся в материалах по русско-японской войне. Деталей не помню, отложилось только название - именно из-за его необычности. 
Объяснить это с точки зрения каких-то норм русского языка невозможно. Может мода тогда была, может пошло от какой-то фамилии, еще раньше искаженно зафиксированной в документах.

Странно, а гугл таких названий не знает. 
Вернее знает, но... в Канаде и на Аляске.

Comment: Мой гугл увидел объявление о снятии дома в районе Владимирофка. Само фото выложила в Инстаграм Волочкова, я же нашёл его на сайте Эха Москвы. Указатель видно на заднем плане левой фотографии (в правой части). Не думаю, что фотошоп.

Comment: Да, нет, я не то имел в виду. Сам указатель я видел, прочитать не могу достоверно.  
А насчет гугла - я про гуглокарты. В объявлении же может быть опечатка. Я тут больше доверяю своей памяти (наряду с указателем, конечно). Не мог я эту историю придумать...